# Change font size for individual code listings

Tags: beamer, listings, fontsize

I would like to reduce the font size within a (beamer) document for some code listings; to allow an occasional larger program to fit on a slide.

I have in the past used `\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\tiny]`, but this approach  requires also to set the sizes of `identifierstyle`, `commentstyle`, `stringstyle`, and `keywordstyle`. Each of these categories also requires their colours to be set again; or default to black. (I am also not aware of how to obtain existing colours/fonts for these categories.)

Setting the font size overall (via `\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}`) will produce the sought result on the slide in question - with the desired syntax colouring - but of course all other text in the document is affected. Is there a way to change the font for individual slides for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```latex
\documentclass{beamer} 

\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{minted}

\newtcblisting{mycodelisting}[1]{%
  listing engine=minted,
  minted style=default,
  minted language=python,
  minted options={fontsize=#1},
  listing only
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Test}
normalsize
\begin{mycodelisting}{\normalsize}
v0 = 6.4
g = 9.81
t = 1
y = v0*t - 0.5*g*t**2
print(y)
\end{mycodelisting} 
scriptsize
\begin{mycodelisting}{\scriptsize}
v0 = 6.4
g = 9.81
t = 1
y = v0*t - 0.5*g*t**2
print(y)
\end{mycodelisting} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Fascinating. I am working with the Rust syntax highlighter from [here](https://github.com/denki/listings-rust). I'll investigate compatibility when I'm back at my workstation.

Comment: This is my first look at minted, and I'm quite impressed. For others using pdflatex, note that the `--shell-escape` flag is required. I was glad to see that although it isn't listed [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted), Rust *is* supported. (btw. I noticed an unexpected box appears around the ellipsis when using a C++11 template pack declaration following the `class` keyword.)